# Spark process file in chunks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, chunks

I would like to process chunks of data (from a csv file) and then do some analysis within each partition/chunk. 
How do I do this and then process these multiple chunks in parallel fashion? I'd like to run map and reduce on each chunk

Comment: What exactly is a chunk for you? If a chunk can be defined by e.g. an ID in your data, you can `keyBy` this Id and then `reduceByKey` to aggregate your values and do the analysis

Comment: I want to be able to read n% of a file. Each map will process n%. The file is randomized and I wish to read it that way rather than group by key

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can read only part of a file. Also I'm not quite sure if I understand your intent correctly or if you understood the concept of Spark correctly.

If you read a file and apply `map` function on the `Dataset`/`RDD`, Spark will automatically process the function in parallel on your data.
That is, each worker in your cluster will be assigned to a partition of your data, i.e. will process "n%" of the data. Which data items will be in the same partition is decided by the partitioner. By default, Spark uses a Hash Partitioner.

(Alternatively to `map`, you can apply `mapParititions`)

Here are some thoughts that came to my mind:

- partition your data using the `partitionBy` method and create your own partitioner. This partitioner can for example put the first `n` rows into partition 1, the next `n` rows into partition 2, etc.
- If your data is small enough to fit on the driver, you can read the whole file, `collect` it into an array, and skip the desired number of rows (in the first run, no row is skipped), take the next `n` rows, and then create an RDD again of these rows.
- You can preprocess the data, create the partitons somehow, i.e. containing the n% and then store it again. This will create different files on your disk/HDFS: `part-00000`, `part-00001`, etc. Then in your actual program you can read just the desired part file, one after the other...